# How to click a pop up using code

Tags: javascript

I've just gotten into code and made this

```
setInterval(function() {
if ($('Text').is(":visible") === true) {
document.getElementById('text').getElementsByClassName('Yes').Click();
} }, 5000);
```

I don't think it works and probably has a lot of problems with it and I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Nobody can guess how the markup looks like, so provide everything what is related, the pseudo - code is not really helpful

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns an array, so use 0th index. Also, it should be `click()` not `Click()`

Comment: Your code has lot of problems. please add your html also

Answer (score 0):

What are you going to achieve?

```
document.getElementById('text').getElementsByClassName('Yes').Click();
```

won't works, because

1. document.getElementById returns just one element, you can access to its
   children using children property (or childNodes).
2. getElementsByClassName returns common array of elements. If you read some JS tutorial you should know how to access it.
3. HTMLElement have no Click() method, but click()

Also you shouldn't mix pure JS with jQuery.

Comment: I'm trying to make it so that the code checks for an element on a page and it clicks it. I also don't know how to test if it works or not.

Comment: @Jeff When you build something from scratch I suggest you to test it in browser console with console.log.
For example - at first print element with id 'test' to check if it exists, next all its children etc.
In this case you can also use document.querySelector to easily get correct element (if you know basics of CSS):
var element = document.querySelector('#text > .Yes');
element.click();
For future reference - if you are not sure how to do something - google it.

Comment: `setInterval(function() {
if($('#watching').is(":visible") === true) {
$(html).find('#stillWatching').click();
} }, 5000);`